# How to debug lsp-mode "lsp-request: method not found"?

Tags: lsp-mode

I've setup `lsp-mode` and `clangd`, and put the `compile-commands.json` in the projects root.

I can tell `compile-commands.json` because my cflags are included in the `Updating file` output of `*clangd::stderr*` log.

---

However, whenever I run `lsp-find-definition` it simply prints:
`lsp-request: method not found`

... unless the function happens to be defined in the same file.

---

How to troubleshoot this? it makes `lsp-mode` quite useless.

Checking the logs gives no hints as to why it fails to find the method.

---

For reference this is the output of `lsp-describe-session`:

```
[-] /src/blender/
 `-[-] clangd:22663
    |-[-] Buffers
    |  |-[+] BKE_blender.h
    |  `-[+] creator.c
    `-[-] Capabilities
       |-[X] workspaceSymbolProvider: t
       |-[X] textDocumentSync: 2
       |-[-] signatureHelpProvider:
       |  `-[X] triggerCharacters: [( ,]
       |-[X] renameProvider: t
       |-[X] referencesProvider: t
       |-[X] hoverProvider: t
       |-[-] executeCommandProvider:
       |  `-[X] commands: [clangd.applyFix]
       |-[X] documentSymbolProvider: t
       |-[X] documentRangeFormattingProvider: t
       |-[-] documentOnTypeFormattingProvider:
       |  |-[X] moreTriggerCharacter: []
       |  `-[X] firstTriggerCharacter: }
       |-[X] documentHighlightProvider: t
       |-[X] documentFormattingProvider: t
       |-[X] definitionProvider: t
       |-[-] completionProvider:
       |  |-[X] triggerCharacters: [. > :]
       |  `-[X] resolveProvider: nil
       `-[X] codeActionProvider: t
```

Answer (score 0):

Do lsp-describe-session and expand server capabilities. This view also displays information about file->buffer associations. My guess is that you do not have a language server associated with that buffer.

Comment: Added output of `lsp-describe-session`, note that I managed to get `ccls` working (out of the box).

Comment: I have this same problem. and ccls works. so just witch to ccls.

Comment: even eglot + clangd works, maybe it's a bug about lsp-mode?